# Entity Framework 6 cannot remove entity

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to delete an entity.

When I call:

```
_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
```

I get an exception saying the entity is not in the objectstatemanager.  When I inspect the contents of the data context, the entity is in the datacontext.  How can an entity be in the datacontext but not be in the objectstatemanager?  I have ProxyCreationEnabled set to false.

**EDIT 1**

I have tried the following:

```
var exists = Set<TEntity>().Any(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
if (!exists)
{
    Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
}

exists = Set<TEntity>().Local.Any(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

if (!exists)
{
    GetQuery<TEntity>().Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).Load();
}

Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
```

However I still get the exception that the object is not in the objectStateManager.

Comment: _When I inspect the contents of the data context, the entity is in the datacontext._ Are you sure? How did you check that?

Comment: By going into the Debugger and inspecting the dbContext and seeing the entities in the proper DbSet collection as well as the 'Local'.

Comment: Actually, it appears the entity is in the dbContext but not in the 'Local' collection.  How is that possible?

Comment: After I perform the code in the Edit, the Entity appears to be in Local as well.

Comment: Also, when I inspect the Context and go all the way into the ObjectStateManager and inspect the _unchangedEntityStore, the entity I am trying to delete is there.  What in the world is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try attach the entity first.

```
_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
```

Or just change the state as deleted.

```
_dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Comment: @BitFiddler, could you try just do either of both code above in my answer, without loading the query if it doesn't exist `GetQuery<TEntity>().Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).Load();`

Comment: Lovely, so when I remove all the attaching code and just try to change the state to deleted, a different exception: failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.  WTF?  If they have the same type and Key, shouldn't EF realise they are the same entity?